# How to make WinServer's AD work with Linux DNS/DHCP on VMware?

Tags: linux, vmware, dns, dhcp, active-directory

I got 2 virtual machines :

1. Windows Server 2008 with Active Directory installed.
2. Linux that works as a DNS and DHCP Server

I need to make them work together, but I don't if this is going to be possible because VMWARE is sharing the NIC with other virtual machines and computer itself.

I've assigned different IP static adresses to the servers.

Is there a way for me to make these things get interconnected and test them on some virtual clients? Any help would be much appreciated... (useful links,tutorials,..)

---

Actually, I read that you can assign different IP Adresses to the same NIC on VMWare Fusion, so that you can be able to give yours servers static IPs and make them work together.

I just need to know how to enable that feature if it's not enabled by default.

I need to connect my virtual clients boxes (windows or linux) against Active directory using the Linux DNS and getting IPs from its DHCP Server.

That's the purpose of all this, and that's also what makes it a bit complicated...

The most difficult task would be to make those servers communicate together, I read I had to use Host-Only network on Linux Server and Bridged on my Windows Server.

Answer (score 0):

From what you have provided, it should work.

Windows recommends AD use a static IP, however it is not a requirement.  You do *not* have to use AD as your networks DNS server, and use your Linux server as the DNS server.

Since they are virtual machines, I assume you want to segregate them from the rest of your LAN.  For VMWare, you want to use Host-only networking to isolate the VMs from the rest of the network